# Column concatenation

Tags: excel

I've got a spreadsheet containing several sheets and want to put all values from column A from each sheet into a single column on another sheet.

Is this possible?

Alternatively is there an easy way to "flatten" the data for export (each sheet has the same column structure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would open up the macro recorder and then record your manual actions in doing what you want in VBA. The code will be quite simple to understand and then you will be able to edit it as you wish. VBA macros are ideal for this type of mundane data manipulation within a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the VLOOKUP function, but I'm not clear on exactly what you want to do; do you want the new column to contain all the values from column A of sheet 1 followed by all the values from column A of sheet 2, then all values from column A of sheet 3 and so on, or do you want the new sheet to contain the sum (or means, or concatenation) of each of the column As from several other sheets?

Comment: Yes, I want all values from column A sheet 1 followed by sheet 2 etc. Although I can copy/paste them or record a macro I'd prefer a "live list" if it's possible, since the data values on each sheet are subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this command on the sheet where you want to paste all columns

=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1)

The above command is only for extract data from two sheets, however you can add more i.e. Sheet3!A1....